# Default project credentials in GCP Cloud Functions not implicit anymore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a  Google Cloud Function that uses GCP client libraries like the python [`google-cloud-storage` (v2.1.0)](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest):

```py
from google.cloud.storage import Client as StorageClient

storage_client = StorageClient()
bucket = storage_client.bucket("xyz")
```

When no explicit GCP project ID was provided, the deployed function would default to the project ID of the deployment.

This behavior seems to have recently changed because:

- A) I don't see any mention of the project-based defaults in the [Application Default Credentials (ADC) docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc)
- and B) I have to specify the `project` when constructing the `Client` for the function to work:

```py
from google.cloud.storage import Client as StorageClient

storage_client = StorageClient(project="abc") # <---
bucket = storage_client.bucket("xyz")
```

I don't see any significant **recent** (<2mo) changes in the [Changelog on GH](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) nor in the [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/release-notes).

Obviously, I can attach dedicated service accounts for each service & function — [as advised in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#attached-sa)…

But I have a bunch of such functions in production **so I wonder if I need to update all of them?**

Comment: Weird, I tested it recently and normally no need to set the project ID in the clients.

The clients should determine the current project from the context.

Comment: thanks for checking @MazlumTosun! There are indeed no changes -- it was a local/development env error, not a production one after all.

Answer (score 1):

The project is an attribute of your identification. Some API requires the projectID, other not.

In the case of GCS, to read and write into a bucket, the project is useless: Buckets are global ressources.

However, if you use the client to create a bucket, you must specify the host project for the bucket. And this time the project is important.

---

So, should you update all your functions? It depends of what you do in your functions as explained above.

Comment: Good point on the globality of buckets. But I use GCS to write to the buckets that "belong" / are associated with the project the CF is deployed to. The buckets have Uniform access control, FWIW.

Comment: One more consideration: the buckets are already _created_ -- the CF only _(re)writes_ files in one single bucket associated with that CF.

That's why it's confusing that GCS used to default to the project credentials but now it doesn't seem to.

Comment: I forgot to mention something: the project used when you read and write on Cloud Storage (and more globally with you use API) is the quota project: It means the api calls are aggregate on that project and, if you reach a quota, the api call will be blocked.

Comment: Hmm, right. But adding a project ID to the client initializer fixed our issue. So I suppose the API wasn't blocked after all?